# Unable to read from a file

Tags: c++, c, file-io

I have written a code that reads from a file named network.dat

The code I wrote is

```
    f = fopen("network.dat", "r");
    if(f == NULL)
        exit(1);
    int read, N;

    printf("%p\n", f);//output file pointer, included this just to check if file is opened properly
    fscanf(f, "%d%d", &N, &read);//error here
    cout<<N;
```

The file is being opened correctly and am getting the file pointer (`49897488`) as output but the line following it is where program stops working and I don't get `N` as output.
Please tell if other detail is required.
Contents of network.dat are

```
10 1
1   6   1.28646
1   7   1.2585
2   9   1.33856
```

and so on. Am just focusing on first 2 numbers from the file i.e. 10 and 1.

Comment: BTW, you should be using `%p` to print `f`, not `%d`.

Comment: @all, I have corrected the snippet as you all wished. There is a `N` now. But that was not the problem.

Comment: @Srijan, what was the problem?

Comment: Are you sure your file is of the format int,int? So 3,5 or 6,8? If it is not, for example if there is an extra space after the comma, it will fail!

Comment: You need to show what the contents of network.dat are.

Comment: I don't understand the reason for a vote down.

Comment: @Srijan probably because you're not showing us any code...

Comment: @teppic I have added network.dat to the question.

Comment: @hmjd the problem is that file is being opened properly but i am not able to read from it.

Comment: @Srijan try `fscanf(f, "%d %d", &N, &read);`

Comment: @veer what else do you want? This is the snippet that is taking input from file. The code following is regarding the other contents of the file. I just asked for help but am not sure was it a good idea.

Comment: @Srijan ...? I stated you need to post code 2 minutes prior to you adding it. Are you having trouble reading the comments?

Comment: @Srijan Now you've edited the question to correct the problem, it no longer makes sense.

Comment: @Srijan you're probably getting downvoted because you aren't effectively helping us, well, help *you*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I stated in [my comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12239122/unable-to-read-from-a-file#comment16403636_12239122), the problem is that your format specifier is incorrect. Try

```
fscanf(f, "%d%d", &N, &read);
```

Since you're using `cout` I'm fathoming a guess that this is actually C++ code... honestly, you should really **not** be doing this the canonical C way. Instead, use [`ifstream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/ifstream/).

```
std::ifstream input("network.dat");
int N, read;
input >> N >> read;
std::cout << N << ' ' << read << std::endl;
```

Comment: That was a typo, i have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @Srijan can you tell us what the "error" is? What problems are you having? Can you post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: @Srijan I *highly* suggest you use the C++ alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Your scanf() format string is incorrect. "%d,%d" looks for two integers separated by a comma. If you want to read two integers separated by whitespace, just do "%d%d".

Comment: That was a typo, i have corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: If you find that any of the scanf() functions aren't giving what you expect, first check that the format string is correct, then check that you are passing pointers (which you were here).

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work Srijan. The code is a quick and dirty cut and paste job, zero points for style, but it does the job as a test. It seems that the number of fields in the records needs to match the fields in the print format string. I added a 3rd field in your test data on record 1 of 1.9999 and it worked. I doubt this is a technically pure explanation.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <cstring>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::cin;
using std::ios;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
//int read;
//int N;
int res;
FILE *f;


f = fopen("network.dat", "r");
    if(f == NULL)
        exit(1);
    int read, N;
    float f3;

    printf("%p\n", f);//output file pointer, included this just to check if file is opened properly
    for (;;)
        {
    res = fscanf(f, "%d%d%f", &N, &read, &f3);//error here
    if (res <= 0)
        {
        printf("err %d\n",errno);
        break;
        }
    cout<<N << " " << read << "\n";
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code expects all the characters in the file up until the first whitespace to be an int.  If the file doesn't begin with an int, that could be the reason it's failing.